# What are real functions called that go through the origin?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, terminology

I am just wondering whether real functions $f:x\rightarrow y$ that go through the origin $f:0\rightarrow 0$ that have no other root have a special name?

They need not be linear or odd, but monotonicity may be assumed. Examples:

$f_1: x\rightarrow \exp(x)-1$

$f_2: x\rightarrow x^3+x$

$f_3: x\rightarrow \ln(x+1)$.

Do these properties (going through (0,0), monotonic) qualify for a special name?

Comment: Even for polynomials, I don't think there is a specific term.

Comment: I don't know of any name for that class of functions.

Comment: Suggestion: call that class of functions "Fred functions".

Comment: Well I will call them monotonic functions that go through the origin: orig. Mofus